# What's an idiomatic XAML TreeView with CollectionViewGroup groupings?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a `TreeView` that looks like this:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="InspectionResultsTreeView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource InspectionTypeGroupViewSource}, Path=Groups}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource InspectionTypeGroupsTemplate}">
</TreeView>
```

The `ItemsSource` is a keyed resource that goes by the name of `InspectionTypeGroupViewSource`:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="InspectionTypeGroupViewSource" Source="{Binding Results}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Inspection.InspectionType" />
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Inspection" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

The role of this little thing is to take the ViewModel's `Results` property:

```
private ObservableCollection<ICodeInspectionResult> _results;

public ObservableCollection<ICodeInspectionResult> Results
{
    get { return _results; } 
    set { _results = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

...and group it on two levels - first by `InspectionType`, then by `Inspection` - the result is a 3-level hierarchy with inspection types, inspections, and then individual inspection results. At this point a screenshot might help visualizing I guess:

[image: Rubberduck 2.0 Code Inspections toolwindow]

So, the `ItemTemplate` of the `InspectionResultsTreeView` is another keyed resource, by the name of `InspectionTypeGroupsTemplate` - that's the **bold** "inspection type" items:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="InspectionTypeGroupsTemplate" 
                            DataType="{x:Type CollectionViewGroup}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource InspectionGroupsTemplate}">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="4,0,4,0" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Text="{Binding ItemCount, StringFormat=({0})}" 
                   TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And the `ItemTemplate` of that template is an `InspectionGroupsTemplate` - that's the individual inspections, with the "severity" icons:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="InspectionGroupsTemplate"
                          DataType="{x:Type CollectionViewGroup}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource InspectionResultTemplate}">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Style="{StaticResource IconStyle}" 
               Source="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource InspectionIconConverter}}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Margin="4" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource InspectionDescriptionConverter}}"
                   TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,4,0,4" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Text="{Binding ItemCount, StringFormat=({0})}" 
                   TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Lastly, the `ItemTemplate` of this grouping is an `InspectionResultTemplate`, which is for each individual inspection result:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InspectionResultTemplate" 
              DataType="{x:Type inspections:ICodeInspectionResult}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Margin="4"
                   Text="{Binding Name}" 
                   TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

The `ICodeInspectionResult` interface has a `string Name` property that I'm using here; this `Name` is different from the `Name` that's used in the grouping levels, where it's an `object CollectionViewGroup.Name` - the underlying type of that `Name` is that of the grouping, so level 1 is an `InspectionType`, and level 2 is an `Inspection`.

The problem is that I'm using more converters than I believe I'd need to, to convert this `object Name` and access the members I need to access and display... but then, I need to display the number of items in each grouping so the `DataType` ought to be a `CollectionViewGroup`... right?

How can I do this without resorting to a converter for everything that needs to be displayed? How is this *supposed* to be done? Every `TreeView` / `CollectionViewGroup` tutorial I could find was a trivial implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've encountered the iconic problem with XAML: it's almost *too* structured.

The *most* idiomatic solution is writing a custom WPF User Control. (How and what you include in it is up you.) The goal of the WPF User Control is to eliminate the duplicate XAML markup and logic. You can include your `Converter` in the User Control, and eliminate the converters from your main control.

There are plenty of tutorials on creating `UserControl` objects in WPF, so I'll not go into detail here.

---

As far as the `Converter` issue: this is *almost* the most idiomatic way. Each converter is reusable, and focuses only on one source type. There's not much else you can do about it, except consider merging converters that support the same source type together. (There's a reason the converter has a `Type targetType` parameter, and an `object parameter`.)